# How to create XHTML code using summernote?

Tags: xhtml, wysiwyg

I'm searching for a wysiwyg editor for X-HTML. I have searched for them and many of them are available on the internet but I found summernote easy for HTML. I want to use summernote to produce XHTML. Can someone please tell me how to do it ?

I have seen summernote being used to xhtml in POMMO mailer.

Comment: I don't know, but try embedding the summernote editor in an XHTML page.

Comment: I have tried by no help.